# add class to div if window.hash.location matches data-attr

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im working on a ReactJS project where Im trying to add a class to all divs when the window hash location matches the data-attr. But I really don't know how to approach this. Anyone who can point me in the right direction how to approach this?

My component has several filter buttons, which adds a #hashname to the url. Then I want to hide all other divs that dosent match.

**Here is a picture of the view:**

[image]

And here is the markup with where every div has `data-label=`

[image]

Comment: Please add the code you've tried.

Comment: $('[data-label]').each(function(){ if ($(this).attr('data-label')==myHashValue) { $(this).show(); } else { $(this).hide();  }});